# Linker error only when using -O1 for boost::error_info in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, boost, clang++

I'm working with a piece of code that has a `boost::error_info` typedef inside an anonymous namespace. The code compiles and links fine *unless* I use the `-O1` flag. Here's a minimal example:

> test.cpp
>
> ```
> #include <boost/exception/all.hpp>
>
> namespace {
> typedef boost::error_info< struct tag_err_val, int > err_val;
> }
>
> int main() {
>   err_val(42);
> }
> ```

This compiles and links fine with any of these invocations of clang:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -O0 -o test
$ clang++ test.cpp -O2 -o test
$ clang++ test.cpp -O3 -o test
```

But if I use `-O1` then this happens:

```
$ clang++ test.cpp -O1 -o test
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::fill(char)", referenced from:
  std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > boost::exception_detail::object_hex_dump<boost::error_info<(anonymous namespace)::tag_err_val, int> >(boost::error_info<(anonymous namespace)::tag_err_val, int> const&, unsigned long) in test-30d00d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The problem is 'fixed' by moving the typedef out of the anonymous namespace. But why is this link error only occurring for one optimization level? And what is causing it?

*Note: I'm using boost 1.64 and Apple clang++ 8.1.0*

Comment: Seems like a clang bug, to be honest.